# Duplicity on macos not working, getting: env: python2: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, duplicity, duplicity-backup

I'm trying to run duplicity on macos and I'm getting this error:

> env: python2: No such file or directory

IMHO there is a link missing between python2 and python2.7 but I'm not sure

Is it safe to create a link from /usr/bin/python2 to /usr/bin/python for fixing this? Or would it be better to change duplicity to use /usr/bin/python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a symlink, but it is better to create it in `/usr/local/bin/` or somewhere else where your normal user account has access, rather than globally in `/usr/bin/` (which requires root access to modify).

Personally, I find if your install `brew` and Python from brew, not only do you get the latest Python builds, but it also manages these path problems for you.

Read more about brew at https://brew.sh/